# nginx - flush() not working when running through CLI

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, flush, command-line-interface

I am working on a PHP script which uses `flush()` function of PHP.

It is working fine on my web browser but not working when I run command through CLI.

Note - I am using nginx server, it is working fine with apache server.

Any solution?

Comment: What's the connection between CLI and web server?

Comment: When using apache web server - flush() function works fine but when i run it through nginx server, it gives me timeout error

Comment: And where is CLI here? How does timeout and flush connected?

Comment: Check this example - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#54841 ....here i put my script in loop which will open firever and execute request when getting some trigger. So unless get any trigger, it shows "waiting" message - this scenario working in apache cli but when i am executing it using nginx server under cli, its not working - gives timeout error

Comment: I guess, you're lookging for [fastcgi_buffering](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_buffering) directive.